# Discord bot with Neural Intents

Tags: python, discord.py

This is a discord bot that i am working on having learned it from watching the youtube video by neuralnine. I wonder if there could be some optimization somewhere.

```py
import discord
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant

chatbot = GenericAssistant('intents.json')
chatbot.train_model()
chatbot.save_model()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    channel = client.get_channel(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
    await channel.send("What's up? Who's got the bud?")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.channel.id != XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
        return
    if message.content.startswith(""): 
        response = chatbot.request(message.content)
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Comment: async def on_ready(): - what are you passing through this function?

Comment: there is a json file associated with it that contains the vocabulary of possible questions and responses